# Conditional Blade component slots

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I have a Blade component called persons, that has different slots I'd like to fill.

```html
<div class="person">
  <img src="{{ $image_url }}" alt="{{ $image_alt }}">
  {{ $name }}
  {{ $information }}
  <a class="button button-primary" href="{{ $link }}" target="_blank">Homepage</a>
</div>
```

And I have various template files, where I'm doing a foreach and I'd like to use the persons component to show the info.

```html
@if ($persons)
  @foreach ($persons as $person)
    @component('components.person')
      @slot('image_url')
        {{ $person['person_image'] }}
      @endslot

      @slot('name')
        {{ $person['person_name'] }}
      @endslot

      @slot('information')
        {!! $person['person_information'] !!}
      @endslot

      @slot('link')
        {{ $person['person_link'] }}
      @endslot
    @endcomponent
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Sometimes some fields might be empty. For example, sometimes somebody doesn't have an image or a homepage and in that case I'd wouldn't want to show that empty field on the homepage.

Logic says that I should add issset() or empty() into my component file, like this:

```html
<div class="person">
  @empty ($image_url)
    <img src="{{ $image_url }}" alt="{{ $image_alt }}">
  @endempty
  
  @isset ($name)
    {{ $name }}
  @endisset
  
  @isset ($information)
    {{ $information }}
  @endisset
  
  @isset ($link)
    <a class="button button-primary" href="{{ $link }}" target="_blank">Homepage</a>
  @endisset  
</div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all. It either removes everything or nothing at all ( depending on if using @isset() or @empty() ).

So my question is: Is it possible to fill component slots conditionally in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

This is from a while ago, but you can use the null coalesce operator to define a default

```
<div class="person">
  <img src="{{ $image_url }}" alt="{{ $image_alt }}">
  {{ $name ?? '' }}
  {{ $information ?? '' }}
  <a class="button button-primary" href="{{ $link }}" target="_blank">Homepage</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `@if` and the null coerce operator and set the default value:

```blade
<div class="person">
  @if ($image_url ?? null)
    <img src="{{ $image_url }}" alt="{{ $image_alt ?? '' }}">
  @endif
  
  <span>{{ $name ?? 'No name' }}</span>
  
  {{ $information ?? null }}

  
  @if ($link ?? null)
    <a class="button button-primary" href="{{ $link }}" target="_blank">Homepage</a>
  @endif 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is better to check them in the upper level as you said, but notice that you should pass something into slots if they have name slot, so you should call:

```
@slot('myslot')
  @if($myobject->value)
    <h5>
       Show
    </h5>
  @endif
@endslot
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
@isset($qualitycheck)
   <a class="dropdown-item p-2" href="{{ $qualitycheck }}">Quantity Check</a>
@endisset
```